# Accessviolationexception vb .NET framework 3.5

Tags: vb.net, access-violation

I am having an `AccessViolationException`"attempted to read or write protected memory ..." when the code tries to invoke a `MyBase.ShowDialog()` of a simple Windows form.

It's a Windows form application coded with vb.NET framework 3.5 using visual studio 2008.

I've looked through the internet but found nothing.

The stackTrace says:

```
en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
en System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(Message& msg)
en System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
en System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
en System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
en System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
```

The point is that it doesn't even happen all the time, the form is declarated as follows:

```
<CLSCompliant(True)> Public Class FMensaje
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

And the function that raises the exception:

```
Public Overloads Function Show(ByVal strMensaje As String, ByVal enmTMensaje As en_TipoMensaje) As MsgBoxResult
    Try
        lblAviso.Text = strMensaje
        ...
        MyBase.ShowDialog()
        Me.BringToFront()
        Application.DoEvents()
        Show = m_mbrResultado
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the same happen with a new sample project? Some limited code that reproduces it is probably the only way anyone can help.

Comment: Hi Deanna, I've updated my question giving further information, thanks for answering

Comment: `MyBase.ShowDialog(); Me.BringToFront()` will be odd anyway as `ShowDialog()` is modal, the form will close, then you tru and bring the (unloaded/invisible) form to the front. `MyBase` and `Me` will be effectively the same object unless you're overriding one of them.

Comment: I've changed MyBase.ShowDialog(); for Me.ShowDialog() and deleted  Me.BringToFront() but the exception still raises :(